# Number Game: Can't Win: Won't print: You Win, but ends script

Tags: python

My issue is that python script ends when I get the number right, but doesn't print: `You win!`

```
import random 

number = random.randint(1,100) # This part works fine

guess = input('Guess a number between 1 and 100: ') #Asks question
guess = float(guess)

tries = 10 

while guess != number and tries > 0 :

    if guess < number:    # This part works fine
        print('Too low')
        tries = tries - 1
        print('You have %s tries left' % (tries))

    if guess > number:
        print('Too high')     # This part is also good
        tries = tries - 1
        print('You have %s tries left' % (tries))

    if tries == 0:
        print('You lose!')
        print('The answer was ' + str(number)) 
        continue

    if guess == number :
        print('You win!')   # Why doesn't this work?
        #Python ends at this line if I get it right, but doesn't print: You win!

    else :
       guess = input('Try Again: ')
       guess = float(guess)

pass     # WHILE*
```

*I'm only 11, and just started programming a couple months ago, please help me!*

Comment: Maybe it prints it but closes the window immediately after so you don't have time to see it?

Comment: That's not it..

Answer (score 2):

Your code fails the first condition if a guess is correct:

```
while guess != number and tries > 0 :
```

If a guess is complete the loop will break after your else statement and never returns to the `if` condition checking for a guess.

Since you can't continue past the loop until a correct answer is inputted you could always write this as follows:

```
import random 

number = random.randint(1,100) # This part works fine

guess = input('Guess a number between 1 and 100: ') #Asks question

guess = float(guess)

tries = 10 

while guess != number and tries > 0 :

    if guess < number:    # This part works fine
        print('Too low')
        tries = tries - 1
        print('You have %s tries left' % (tries))

    if guess > number:
        print('Too high')     # This part is also good
        tries = tries - 1
        print('You have %s tries left' % (tries))

    if tries == 0:
        print('You lose!')
        print('The answer was ' + str(number)) 
        continue

    else :
       guess = input('Try Again: ')
       guess = float(guess)

print('You win!')
```

Bear in mind there's a bug in this that will cause you win to also be printed after the user runs out of guesses. I've decided to leave this here as I think it's easy to fix and would be good for you to resolve yourself to learn from. Feel free to write in the comments if you want me to do that for you however.

I would also recommend using code comments on your posts. In this case I would have presented the code for your question as follows:

```
import random 

number = random.randint(1,100) # This part works fine

guess = input('Guess a number between 1 and 100: ') #Asks question

guess = float(guess)

tries = 10 

while guess != number and tries > 0 :

    if guess < number:    # This part works fine
        print('Too low')
        tries = tries - 1
        print('You have %s tries left' % (tries))

    if guess > number:
        print('Too high')     # This part is also good
        tries = tries - 1
        print('You have %s tries left' % (tries))

    if tries == 0:
        print('You lose!')
        print('The answer was ' + str(number)) 
        continue

    if guess == number :
        print('You win!')       # Why doesn't this work?
                # Python ends at this line if I get it right, but doesn't print: You win!

    else :
       guess = input('Try Again: ')
       guess = float(guess)

pass     # WHILE*
```

Comment: This is not a syntax error (at least in python 2, is it in Python 3 ???)

Answer (score 1):

When doing comparisons in your code, it is often best to try and only ask a particular question (do a comparison) once.  Here I showed a way to restructure your two questions (correct guess & out of tries) to only do the questions once.

```
import random

number = random.randint(1, 100) 
guess = input('Guess a number between 1 and 100: ')  # Asks question
guess = float(guess)

tries = 10
while True:
    tries -= 1

    if guess < number:
        print('Too low')
        print('You have %s tries left' % (tries))

    elif guess > number:
        print('Too high')
        print('You have %s tries left' % (tries))

    else:
        print('You win!')
        break

    if tries == 0:
        print('You lose!')
        print('The answer was ' + str(number))
        break

    guess = input('Try Again: ')
    guess = float(guess)
```